# Is this a correct/safe way to define and use "interfaces" in pure C

Tags: c, class, pointers, interface, casting

for the past few months I've been trying to code in pure C and avoid C++ as much as I can (for personal reasons, C++ is a nice language in deed), but once in a while there comes situations where I miss some concepts that I used to be using a lot back when I coded in C++, which there is no obvious equivalent in C for them, one of those concepts being "Interface". so after a few hours of research I came up with this solution but I'm afraid that my code might go wrong sometime in the future. Below is the sample code of what I want to do:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int (*on_affected_cb) (const char *msg);

typedef struct affectee_t affectee_t;
typedef struct type_a_t type_a_t;
typedef struct type_b_t type_b_t;
typedef struct type_c_t type_c_t;
typedef struct owner_t owner_t;

//******************************************************************************

struct affectee_t{ //interface
  on_affected_cb on_affected;
};

void affectee_notify(affectee_t* self, const char* msg){
  self->on_affected(msg);
}

//******************************************************************************

struct type_a_t{ //implementor a
  affectee_t affectee;
  int num;
};

static int type_a_on_affected (const char *msg){
  printf("this is type a reading msg: %s\n", msg);
  return 1000;
}

void type_a_init(type_a_t* self){
  self->num = 0;
  self->affectee.on_affected = type_a_on_affected;
}

//******************************************************************************

struct type_b_t{ //implementor b
  affectee_t affectee;
  char name[128];
};

static int type_b_on_affected (const char *msg){
  printf("this is type b reading msg: %s\n", msg);
  return 2000;
}

void type_b_init(type_b_t* self){
  memset(self->name, 0, sizeof(self->name));
  self->affectee.on_affected = type_b_on_affected;
}

//******************************************************************************

struct owner_t{ // ordinary struct/class
  type_a_t ta;
  type_b_t tb;
};

void owner_init(owner_t* self){
  type_a_init(&self->ta);
  type_b_init(&self->tb);
}

void owner_notify(owner_t* self){
  const char msg[] = "what the f...!";
  affectee_notify((affectee_t*)&self->ta, msg); //<- pointer casting!!!
  affectee_notify((affectee_t*)&self->tb, msg); //<- same here
}

//******************************************************************************

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  owner_t owner;
  owner_init(&owner);
  owner_notify(&owner);
}
```

Comment: You should use `&self->ta.affectee` instead of `(affectee_t*)&self->ta`.

Comment: I think this question is more appropriate for codereview.

Comment: Usually you define the abstract class as a struct of methods, plus a void pointer to a struct that contains all private members. It's also good to provide one "class-static" member method to that gets the void-pointer from the self-pointer, e.g.`struct private_data * = get_private_data(self)`.  Another problem of your code is, your methods of your interface does not accept self-pointer (should be `affectee_t*` type), so it's impossible to get access to the private data members, and this mistake makes your "interface" idea impossible to use.